# Multiple regression or multivariate regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-regression

Are there any difference in beta coefficients when doing several multiple regression analysis as compared to doing multivariate regression?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no"

```
x = matrix(rnorm(200),100)
y = matrix(rnorm(200),100)

bhat = solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
bhat1 = solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y[,1]
bhat2 = solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y[,2]

all.equal(cbind(bhat1,bhat2),bhat)
```

Comment: I'd be interested in an explanation that uses some narrative in addition to the code.